# Unable to fetch the input values from the form in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am fetching the values from the form page and then validating it. I am using jquery to handle the input objects and fetch the values which are entered by the user.

My HTML code is:

```
<form id="userDetails">

  <table class="containFormTable" cellspacing="8">

    <tr>
      <td class="detail">Name:</td>
      <td>
        <input name="name" type="text" id="name" />
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="detail">Email-Id:</td>
      <td>
        <input name="emailId" type="text" id="emailId">
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="detail">Phone-No:</td>
      <td>
        <input name="phoneNo" type="text" id="phoneNo">
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" style="padding-top: 50px">
        <input type="button" value="Submit" id="submit">
      </td>
    </tr>



  </table>


</form>
```

My javascript file code which is fetching the data is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#submit').click(function() {

    var name = $('#name').find('input[name="name"]').val();

    var emailId = $('#emailId').find('input[name="emailId"]').val();

    var phoneNo = $('#phoneNo').find('input[name="phoneNo"]').val();

  });
});
```

The result I am getting in the variable name or any other is "undefined".
Where am I going wrong in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove `.find('input[name="name"]')` from each selector

```js
$(document).ready(function(){




                        $('#submit')
                            .click(
                                    function() {

                                        var name = $('#name').val();

                                        var emailId = $('#emailId').val();

                                        var phoneNo = $('#phoneNo').val();

console.log(name);
                                      console.log(emailId);
                                      console.log(phoneNo);
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="userDetails">

                <table class="containFormTable" cellspacing="8">

                    <tr>
                        <td class="detail">Name:</td>
                        <td><input name="name" type="text" id="name"/></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td class="detail">Email-Id:</td>
                        <td><input name="emailId" type="text" id="emailId"></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td class="detail">Phone-No:</td>
                        <td><input name="phoneNo" type="text" id="phoneNo"></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr >
                    <td colspan="2" style="padding-top: 50px"><input type="button" value="Submit" id="submit"></td>
                    </tr>



                </table>


            </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is get the value from the elements, like this:

```
var name = $('#name').val();
var emailId = $('#emailId').val();
var phoneNo = $('#phoneNo').val();
```

Your code was getting a reference to the form fields, then looking for child elements (which `input` elements don't have, hence `undefined`) that were the same as the element that you already found and then trying to get the value of that.